# construir una baraja de cartas usando un ciclo For

Tags: java

Tengo un string `String str_one = "\uD83C\uDCA2"` que me pinta una carta de poker pero quisiera saber si es posible generar todas las cartas con un ciclo `for`.

He intentado reemplazar los 2 últimos caracteres, pero no he podido.
Tampoco teniendo algo como `String str_two = "uD83CuDCA2"` y luego usar el str_two.replaceAll("u", "\u")

Necesito saber si hay otra forma de generar las cartas aprovechando el patrón que tienen en su representación `Unicode`.

No tiene que ser con strings, puede ser con Character o con una representación hexadecimal, sólo quiero saber si es posible generar las 52 cartas aprovechando el patrón que tienen.

Actualización:

He usado el string "symbol" como está a continuación para la creación de una carta y los métodos set y get para "symbol" y "value", pero más adelante necesitaré el entero "codepoint", cómo me regreso del string "symbol" al entero "codepoint" ?

```
for (int c2 = 1, value=1; c2 <= 0xE; c2++, value++) {
    for (int c1 = 0xA; c1 <= 0xD; c1++) {
        if (c2!=0xC) {
            str = String.format("1F0%X%X", c1, c2);
            codePoint = Integer.parseInt(str, 16);
            symbol = String.format("%c", codePoint);

            cards.add(new Card (symbol, value));
        } else {
            value = 11;
        }
    }
    System.out.println();
}
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

De acuerdo con [*Wikipedia*](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Playing_cards_in_Unicode), los códigos Unicode (en hexadecimal) para las cartas de poker tienen el siguiente patrón: comienzan con `1F0`, luego una letra, de la `A` a la `D`; después un número o letra, del `1` al `9` o de la `A` a la `E`.

❐ *Código:*

En Java es posible representar un número en hexadecimal de manera *literal*. Sólo hay que añadir el prefijo `0x` al número deseado. Y esto se puede aprovechar para crear dos ciclo `for` anidados, uno para el primer carácter y el otro para el segundo carácter. Es decir:

```java
for (int c1 = 0xA; c1 <= 0xD; c1++) {
    for (int c2 = 1; c2 < 0xE; c2++) {
        String str = String.format("1F0%X%X", c1, c2);
        int codePoint = Integer.parseInt(str, 16);
        System.out.printf("%c U+%s %s%n", codePoint, str, Character.getName(codePoint));
    }
}
```

`c1` va de `0xA` a `0xD` y `c2` va de `0x1` a `0xE`, tal como se requiere.

❐ *Salida:*

```
 U+1F0A1 PLAYING CARD ACE OF SPADES
 U+1F0A2 PLAYING CARD TWO OF SPADES
 U+1F0A3 PLAYING CARD THREE OF SPADES
 U+1F0A4 PLAYING CARD FOUR OF SPADES
 U+1F0A5 PLAYING CARD FIVE OF SPADES
 U+1F0A6 PLAYING CARD SIX OF SPADES
 U+1F0A7 PLAYING CARD SEVEN OF SPADES
 U+1F0A8 PLAYING CARD EIGHT OF SPADES
 U+1F0A9 PLAYING CARD NINE OF SPADES
 U+1F0AA PLAYING CARD TEN OF SPADES
 U+1F0AB PLAYING CARD JACK OF SPADES
 U+1F0AC PLAYING CARD KNIGHT OF SPADES
 U+1F0AD PLAYING CARD QUEEN OF SPADES
 U+1F0B1 PLAYING CARD ACE OF HEARTS
 U+1F0B2 PLAYING CARD TWO OF HEARTS
 U+1F0B3 PLAYING CARD THREE OF HEARTS
 U+1F0B4 PLAYING CARD FOUR OF HEARTS
 U+1F0B5 PLAYING CARD FIVE OF HEARTS
 U+1F0B6 PLAYING CARD SIX OF HEARTS
 U+1F0B7 PLAYING CARD SEVEN OF HEARTS
 U+1F0B8 PLAYING CARD EIGHT OF HEARTS
 U+1F0B9 PLAYING CARD NINE OF HEARTS
 U+1F0BA PLAYING CARD TEN OF HEARTS
 U+1F0BB PLAYING CARD JACK OF HEARTS
 U+1F0BC PLAYING CARD KNIGHT OF HEARTS
 U+1F0BD PLAYING CARD QUEEN OF HEARTS
 U+1F0C1 PLAYING CARD ACE OF DIAMONDS
 U+1F0C2 PLAYING CARD TWO OF DIAMONDS
 U+1F0C3 PLAYING CARD THREE OF DIAMONDS
 U+1F0C4 PLAYING CARD FOUR OF DIAMONDS
 U+1F0C5 PLAYING CARD FIVE OF DIAMONDS
 U+1F0C6 PLAYING CARD SIX OF DIAMONDS
 U+1F0C7 PLAYING CARD SEVEN OF DIAMONDS
 U+1F0C8 PLAYING CARD EIGHT OF DIAMONDS
 U+1F0C9 PLAYING CARD NINE OF DIAMONDS
 U+1F0CA PLAYING CARD TEN OF DIAMONDS
 U+1F0CB PLAYING CARD JACK OF DIAMONDS
 U+1F0CC PLAYING CARD KNIGHT OF DIAMONDS
 U+1F0CD PLAYING CARD QUEEN OF DIAMONDS
 U+1F0D1 PLAYING CARD ACE OF CLUBS
 U+1F0D2 PLAYING CARD TWO OF CLUBS
 U+1F0D3 PLAYING CARD THREE OF CLUBS
 U+1F0D4 PLAYING CARD FOUR OF CLUBS
 U+1F0D5 PLAYING CARD FIVE OF CLUBS
 U+1F0D6 PLAYING CARD SIX OF CLUBS
 U+1F0D7 PLAYING CARD SEVEN OF CLUBS
 U+1F0D8 PLAYING CARD EIGHT OF CLUBS
 U+1F0D9 PLAYING CARD NINE OF CLUBS
 U+1F0DA PLAYING CARD TEN OF CLUBS
 U+1F0DB PLAYING CARD JACK OF CLUBS
 U+1F0DC PLAYING CARD KNIGHT OF CLUBS
 U+1F0DD PLAYING CARD QUEEN OF CLUBS
```

<sub>──────────────

NOTA: Dependiendo del navegador (y a veces también del sistema operativo), los caracteres anteriores podrán ser *renderizados* correctamente:</sub>

---

[image: new] *UPDATE*

El código se modifica, de acuerdo con los comentarios del *OP*, como sigue:

```
for (int c1 = 0xA; c1 <= 0xD; c1++) {
    for (int c2 = 1; c2 < 0xE; c2++) {
        if (c2 != 0xC) {
            String str = String.format("1F0%X%X", c1, c2);
            int codePoint = Integer.parseInt(str, 16);
            System.out.println(Character.toChars(codePoint));
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: y si no deseo usar estas?  1F0AC  1F0BC  1F0CC  1F0DC ? qué condición le agrego al for? pongo if (c2 != 0xC) ... ?

Comment: y si no deseo usar el System.out.printf(...) sino que cuando haga System.out.println(myString) me pinte la carta de una vez?? perdona que pregunte pero la verdad no supe qué método usar (busqué en el api)

Comment: @DianaCarolinaHernandez He agregado un código modificado, de acuerdo a tus comentarios. Espero sea de ayuda.

Comment: después de : codePoint = Integer.parseInt(str, 16) usé symbol = String.format("%c", codePoint) pero teniendo este "symbol" cómo me regreso al integer? (ver actualización de pregunta), he probado con Integer.parseint(..., 16) y arroja error.